# the picture wont be loaded in opencart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I'm writing an open cart module that's supposed to load a picture when I hover on some `<li>` tags.
I have two PCs: my laptop on linux and a Windows Desktop, my problem is my module works fine when I load the page on the laptop, but when I load it on my Desktop I can't see the picture, and when I followed the SRC attribute of the picture I found that it has a 1*1 resolution

```
  if ($product_info) 
    {
     if ($product_info['image']) 
     {
       $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], 
                                         $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
       $image_big = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], 300, 300);
     } 
     else 
    {  
      $image = false;
      $image_big = false ;
    }
```

If you are familiar with open cart you will know this code; I can't figure it out.

Does any body see the problem in my code?

Comment: Please go back and edit your message to use some punctuation and proper spelling ("you"...this isn't a text message).

Comment: At least go to my page and see if you see the image with 300*300 under the Meilleur Offres just tell me

Comment: Windows or Linux I think doesn't really matter, what browsers are you using on Linux? FF, CHrome, Konqueror,...?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you've got two different versions of OpenCart on the two machines

There were some changes made to the module system between two different versions of opencart in 1.5.X between the early 1.5 and the current version (1.5.1.3.1)

Comment: no i am viewing the same web site from a webhost not from a local pc